# What is the provenance of the pictures on Kirk's wall?

Tags: star-trek

Around fifteen minutes into *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*, Kirk recorded a log entry while in his quarters.  As the camera panned around the room there were three pictures in frames visible on the walls.
[image: kirk and two pictures]

[image: valeris and the third picture]

**What is the origin of these three pictures?**

My hope is that these are famous paintings or prints and that someone with a better art education than mine will recognize them.  If you have evidence that they are just creations of the movie's set designers, that will also be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I've updated the question with an image of the third picture, which I noticed while watching the scene more carefully.

Comment: The identified whaler ship was done by "NCT (c) LA", and I've found a few other items of scrimshaw/carvings that look like the lighthouse and whales style. Appears to be North Coast Trading Company, a "fakeshaw" producer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The top one appears to be [this one](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Scrimshaw-Charles-W-Morgan-8-X-10-Carving-This-Could-Be-Faux-But-Still-Nice-/161222196026?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2589977b3a)  that's posted on eBay.  Legend refers to the "American Whaler" Charles Morgan whaling ship.  I haven't been able yet to find any additional info.  The eBay site shows several different replicas so it wasn't made just for the film.  No success (so far) in locating the bottom one.

[image]

Comment: The style is "scrimshaw" whereas the one below (the lighthouse & pelicans) appears to be a photograph

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, the only one I could find an entry for IS the blurred panned one. From [Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/database/tos_references.htm):

> TOS planet names:  For TNG: "Conspiracy" a star chart was created by Mike Okuda that comprised all planets seen and mentioned in TOS and TAS. This chart can be seen again in several more episodes, such as "The Emissary", "The Measure of a Man", "The Game" and "The Mind's Eye". It also appears in the classroom aboard Deep Space 9, featuring the heading "The Explored Galaxy", in "In the Hands of the Prophets" and "Cardassians". In addition to episodic Star Trek, it can be seen in Captain Kirk's quarters aboard the USS Enterprise-A in "Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country"

[image: Original image]

[image: PIcture in upper left]
[image: In background]
[image: In Kirk's quarters]

Comment: The Enterprise was not a **clipper** ship, which were late 19th century fast cargo ships for the Asian trade.

Comment: Hmmm, I missed that one.  Probably thought it was a view screen.  Thanks for catching it!

Comment: You are correct, MA lists it as a frigate. Edited to remove, as Stan found the actual print.